# Using for loop and re.search in same line with variables in the pattern

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to search a specific pattern in a line. The patterns are are coming from a list. I tried using the following logic but its saying syntax error. I am not understanding the reason though. Can someone please explain? I am listing below the requirements in my code,

1. I need to search a pattern from each line of the file.
2. The patterns are iterated from a list.
3. I want to enable the pattern search and iterating over the list in one single line of python code rather than doing it in 2 lines.

   ```
   import re
   cell = ['abc', 'def']
   line = '/* Begin cell: abc */'
   for c in cell if re.search(r".*Begin cell.*%s.*" % c, line, re.I):
       print 'Match'
   ```

Error noticed is below,

```
File "<ipython-input-47-241664c42555>", line 5
    for c in cell (if re.search(r".*Begin cell.*%s.*" % c, line, re.I)):
                    ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error has nothing to do with `for` or `re.search`. You just can't have an `if` like that: it needs to be a separate statement.

```
for c in cell:
    if re.search(r".*Begin cell.*%s.*" % c, line, re.I):
        print 'Match'
```

Comment: You can say `[ ... for .... if ... ]` inside a list comprehension, dict comprehension or generator expression, which is where the OP might have picked this syntax up from.   It's just not allowed in line-by-line code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. So that means I cannot do a search operation and have an iterator in the same line. The reason for the question being, I have a large file where in I need to check each line against a list of strings for matching. I know that large file has only at few selective places the matching string. By going with the above code (ie., iterating over the cell followed by the search over each line), I am unnecessarily reading the entire file and cross-checking against the pattern. So wanted to avoid this to improve the runtime.

Comment: That makes no sense. There is **no possible difference** in runtime between what you claim to want to do and what the code is actually doing. Whatever happens, you need to iterate through the file and check each line for a match; even if the syntax allowed you to do it on the same line as the for statement it wouldn't change the runtime.

Comment: To clarify, the "line" string variable is predefined in the example give above. Say if I have to read this list variable (line) from a huge file iteratively, then I am checking the cell pattern list for each line of the file which I wanted to avoid. There are other functions that follows the code (but within the for loop of line reading) which I am performing on the line string variable which doesn't really require the checking of the cell pattern. Hope I was able to explain clearly.